# Mapping a fish eye to a sphere - 360 degree view

Tags: image-processing, unity-game-engine, transform

I am attempting to map a fisheye image to a 360 degree view using a sky sphere in Unity. The scene is inside the sphere. I am very close but I am seeing some slight distortion. I am calculating UV coordinates as follows:

```
Vector3 v = currentVertice; // unit vector from edge of sphere, -1, -1, -1 to 1, 1, 1
float r = Mathf.Atan2(Mathf.Sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y), v.z) / (Mathf.PI * 2.0f);
float phi = Mathf.Atan2(v.y, v.x);
textureCoordinates.x = (r * Mathf.Cos(phi)) + 0.5f;
textureCoordinates.y = (r * Mathf.Sin(phi)) + 0.5f;
```

Here is the distortion and triangles:

[image]

The rest of the entire sphere looks great, it's just at this one spot that I get the distortion.

Here is the source fish eye image:

[image]

And the same sphere with a UV test texture over the top showing the same distortion area. Full UV test texture is on the right, and is a square although stretched into a rectangle on the right for purposes of my screenshot.

[image]

The distortion above is using sphere mapping rather than fish eye mapping. Here is the UV texture using fish eye mapping:

[image]

Math isn't my strong point, am I doing anything wrong here or is this kind of mapping simply not 100% possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spot you are seeing is the case where r gets very close to 1. As you can see in the source image, this is the border area between the very distorted image data and the black.

This area is very distorted, however that's not the main problem. Looking at the result you can see that there are problems with UV orientation.

I've added a few lines to your source image to demonstrate what I mean. Where r is small (yellow lines) you can see that the UV coordinates can be interpolated between the corners of your quad (assuming quads instead of tris). However, where r is big (red corners), interpolating UV coordinates will make them travel through areas of your source image whose r is much smaller than 1 (red lines), causing distortions in UV space. Actually, those red lines should not be straight, but they should travel along the border of your source image data.

You can improve this by having a higher polycount in the area of your skysphere where r gets close to 1, but it will never be perfect as long as your UVs are interpolated in a linear way.

[image]

I also found another problem. If you look closely at the spot, you'll find that the complete source image is present there in small. This is because your UV coordinates wrap around at that point. As rendering passes around the viewer, uv coordinates travel from 0 towards 1. At the spot they are at 1, the neighboring vertex however is at 0.001 or something, causing the whole source image to be rendered inbetween. To fix that, you'll need to have two seperate vertices at the seam of your skysphere, one where the surface of the sphere starts, and one where it ends. In object space they are identical, but in uv space one is at 0, the other at 1.

Comment: The seams run up and around the sphere rather than the equator then, is that right?

Comment: I should mention to that I'm using an octa sphere, with triangles and not quads, although the triangles do share vertices with one another.

Comment: I also added a uv test texture to my question if that changes things or helps at all.

Comment: There are two seams, one on the u-border, one on the v-border. Whether it's tris or quads is not important, the problem should be the same. Are you absolutely sure that your second screenshot, the one using the uv test texture, shows the same area that's distorted in your first screenshot? Because it really should show the same uv orientation problems...

Comment: Sorry my bad. I uploaded a new image with fish eye mapping using the UV texture.

Comment: I changed the seams and the distortion is slightly changed now but mostly still the same

Comment: Yes, having overlapping seams can only solve one part of the problem, the one where two vertices with identical world coords require different UV coords. The other problem which causes the distortion can only be improved but not (to my knowledge) fixed. Increasing the vertex count should improve the distortions. Just quadruple the number of vertices and you should see improvement. You can then try to optimize by having a higher vertex count in the problematic area while keeping it low in the non-problematic areas.

Comment: Increasing the vertex count does help the distortion. Thanks for your help.